# Responsive navigation issue

Tags: html, css

I'm working on my portfolio and having trouble with my logo and nav.

Here is what I'm going for: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPGw1.jpg

I'd like to have it display like that at 3 different break points but currently what I am running into is the nav will run right into logo without dropping below it like I would like it to. I had it working properly before but I'm not sure what went wrong. Any suggestions would be awesome!

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <title>Portfolio</title>
        <script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/lightbox.min.js"></script>
        </script>
        <link href="css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />


</style>


</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
    <div id="logo">
     <h1><a href="">NAME</a></h1>
    </div>
        <div id="nav">

            <ul>
                <li><a href="">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="">ABOUT</a></li>
                <li><a href="">CONTACT</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="content">

        <div class="article column1">
        <a href="new.mp4" rel="shadowbox;height=338;width=600" title="LOGO ANIMATION">         <img class="hoverme" src="images/animation1.jpg"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="article column2">
            <a href="images/northforest.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="Logo Design"> <img class="hoverme" src="images/nfsmall.jpg"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="article column3">
            <a href="images/flyer.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="Flyer"> <img class="hoverme" src="images/flyersmall.jpg"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="article column4">
            <a href="images/menu.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="Flyer"> <img class="hoverme" src="images/menusmall.jpg"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="article column5">
        <a href="images/article.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="Article"> <img class="hoverme" src="images/articlesmall.jpg"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="article column6">
        <a href="ahlogo.mp4" rel="shadowbox;height=338;width=600" title="LOGO ANIMATION"> <img class="hoverme" src="images/animation2.jpg"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">

    </div>

    </div>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="shadowbox.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="shadowbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
Shadowbox.init({
handleOversize:   "resize"
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
    @font-face { 
  font-family: 'bikoblack';
  src: url('fonts/biko_black.otf');
  }

    @font-face { 
  font-family: 'bikoregular';
  src: url('fonts/biko_regular.otf');
  }

.hoverme {

border: 3px solid #d0d0d0;

 }  

 .hoverme:hover {
 opacity: .5;
 -webkit-transition: all .9s ease-in-out;
 -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}

a:link {
    color: #0f4c96;
}
a:visited {
    color: #0f4c96;
}
a:hover {
    color: #b2b1b1;
}
a:active {
    color: #0f4c96;
}

* {
    text-align: center;
    }
body {

    margin: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    background-color: white;
     }
#wrapper {
    max-width:90%;
    margin:0 auto;

}


img {width: 100%; height: 100%;
}


h1 {
    font-family: 'bikoblack';
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 3.5em;
    line-height: 85%;
    color: #0f4c96;
    float: left;


    }
#header {
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}


#nav {

    position:absolute;
    bottom:1.25em;
    right:1em;
    }
li {
    display: inline;
    font-family: 'bikoregular';
    color: #0f4c96;
    padding-left: 2em;
    }


.column1, .column2, .column3, .column4, .column5, .column6 {        
    width: 32.66%;
    height: 15em;
    float: left;
    margin: 1% 1% .01% 0%;

    }       
.column3, .column6 {
    margin-right: 0%;}
    }


@media (max-width:767px) {
h1 {
    float: none;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    }
#nav {
    position:static;
    width:100%;margin:0 auto;
    top: 5em;
}    
    li {
    width:100px;
    padding: 0 1em; 
}
}




@media (max-width:480px){
li {
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
    width:auto;
 }

 }


 a {text-decoration: none; }
```

Comment: what was your last change? I mean after which step it's not working properly anymore.

Comment: The nav currently just flows right into the logo when the screen size is reduced. It does transition to block display when the screen is small but it never drops below the logo like I would like it to. Here is what I am talking about: http://i.imgur.com/PXsAZ2M.jpg and http://imgur.com/HXyfCGu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to do some small changes, you also have some errors in your CSS, both unclosed properties as well as wrong media queries. Try this:

```
.hoverme {
    border: 3px solid #d0d0d0;
}
.hoverme:hover {
    opacity: .5;
    -webkit-transition: all .9s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}
a:link {
    color: #0f4c96;
}
a:visited {
    color: #0f4c96;
}
a:hover {
    color: #b2b1b1;
}
a:active {
    color: #0f4c96;
}
* {
    text-align: center;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    background-color: white;
}
#wrapper {
    max-width:90%;
    margin:0 auto;
}
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#header {
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    display:block;
}
h1 {
    font-family:'bikoblack';
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 3.5em;
    line-height: 85%;
    color: #0f4c96;
    display:block;
    width:35%;
    float:left;
}
#nav {
    display:block;
    width:50%;
    float:right;
    margin-top:1.85em;
}
li {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family:'bikoregular';
    color: #0f4c96;
    padding: 0 1em;
}
.column1, .column2, .column3, .column4, .column5, .column6 {
    width: 32.66%;
    height: 15em;
    float: left;
    margin: 1% 1% .01% 0%;
}
.column3, .column6 {
    margin-right: 0%;
}
@media all and (max-width: 767px) {
    h1 {
        float: none;
        clear:both;
        display:block;
        width:100%;
        text-align:center;
    }
    #nav {
        position:relative;
        display:block;
        width:100%;
        margin:0 auto;
        top: 0em;
        float:none;
        clear:both;
        text-align:center;
    }
    li {
        width:100px;
        padding: 0 1em;
    }
}
@media all and (max-width: 480px) {
    li {
        display:block;
        text-align:center;
        width:auto;
    }
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Of course you'll have to adjust to your needs, but there you have the basics of the layout you're looking for, you can [see a fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/1q66sur3/) so you can play around. Also, make sure to pay attention to how you write your CSS, that's the main part of why your version didn't work

Comment: Thank you sir. I'm new to web design and self taught so every day is a learning experience right now.

Comment: I understand and that's why I'm trying to provide guidance for you pointing out on small mistakes that might break your code without you noticing the reason why